# Purchased character is rigged - but can't change anything

Tags: rigging, bones, rigid-body-simulation, pose-mode

I am new to Blender. I bought a female character that is already rigged and then loaded it into Blender.

[image: This is the Model]

In edit mode, (pose mode) not a single rig bone is displayed to me.
I know from other rigged characters that normally a skeleton should now be visible and this is adjustable accordingly.

[image: The Character without Bones]

However, bones and poses can be found in the Finder. But I can't do anything with them because nothing happens when I click on them.

[image: The Bones are here =)]

I am using the latest version of blender. Help.

Thanks a lot!

David H.

The Character can be found here:
https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/character/woman/black-woman-fit-in-bikini.

Here you can download the project File, if you need to look into

[Here you can download the project File, if you need to look into](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DbF4L430FIq-urCGq7OeSYfv6GSAH8_V?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

There are at least 4 options to hide bones:

- the *Viewport Overlays* are turned off. It's the icon with the two spheres. That's your case here.
- the display of bones in the *Viewport Overlays* is disabled (checkbox)
- the bone layer with the bones is not active (click the the little squares, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select more than one)
- the bone is hidden (<kbd>H</kbd>), switch to *Pose* or *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to reveal the hidden bones. (The *Object* mode shows the same bones as the *Pose* mode.)

Comment: Thank you so much Blunder! =) You are my HERO!

Comment: You're welcome! :-) In your file there are a few poses included. If you use Blender 3.1+ you can convert them to assets for the new Pose Library. This is an add-on the ships with Blender. You might need to enable it in the User Preferences (not sure if it's enabled by default). It's very useful for animation.

Comment: @DavidH Please consider marking the answer as "Accepted Answer" if your question could be answered satisfactorily. You can also express your gratitude with an upvote. [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Thats cool! I have this option active now. Can you tell me where i can see this? I found a another problem. I want to copy this model (with a new pose) into another project - this works so far but i can´t rezise this. Do you know what this could be? With other charackters (from the same creator) works this without problems.

Comment: In a nutshell: https://ibb.co/Kys3TGG <- (1) choose menu *Edit> Preferences* to open the (2) *User Preferences*, select *Addons* & (3) search for "Pose", then tick the checkbox. Now you will see the addon in the (7) *Asset Browser* and the (8) *Animation* tab in the side panel. -- To convert the poses, select the (5) armature "Female" and click (6) the "Convert To Pose Assets" button in the *Object Data Properties* tab. Now you see the poses in (7) and (8). To apply a pose select all bones, double-click a pose icon, or use the "Apply" button. Hope that helps!

Comment: About the scale: If you select the armature in *Object* mode or the bones in *Pose* mode & choose the "Item" tab in the viewport side panel (first tab in the area (8)) then you will notice that the *Scale* input boxes have a closed lock icon right behind them. This locks the values. Scaling the armature is a *bad* idea because it messes up the rig poses. Better go to *Pose* mode, select the root bone (the big circle with the arrows at her feet), and unlock the lock icons for this bone. Now you can scale the bone to make her taller or shorter or turn her into a fairy. Alt+S resets the scale.